# Thread safe, serializable map that allows null as values and should be able to cast it into list in java

Tags: java, data-structures, grails, groovy, hashmap

I was using a groovy lazymap inside a hashmap in my code but I ran into issues with load balancing, so I started using hazelcast map, but since groovy lazymap is not serializable, I couldn't continue to use it. I am looking for a map data structure that is thread safe, serializable, we should be able to add null values into it and should be able to cast it to list due to some execution flow constraints. Is there any such data structure or work around for this

I tried using concurrent hashmap but that doesn't allow null values, I tried synchronised hashmap but that does not get casted to a list

Comment: Consider `Collections.synchronizedMap(new HashMap<>());` - permits null values and serializable